# Managing long text block in a html tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I have a large number of pages containing varying lengths of long text (1000 words+) that I have separated into logical tabs (Summary, Content, References and Authors) using CSS only. The Content tab has far more text than the other tabs and users still end up scrolling like crazy to read through it all.

I would like a way of splitting up the long Content text into sub-tabs or sub-pages, but without allowing the user to navigate away from the main tabbed page (i.e. I still want them to be able to switch between the 4 main tabs (Summary, Content, References and Authors).

I also, do not want to have to go through all the content and manually enter in the breakpoints for the Content section as the content may be changing fairly frequently.

Any ideas about how to split the Content section up to allow the 4 tab navigation and display the Content without having to scroll?

I have created a codepen with a sample of what it currently looks like with html and CSS code:    http://codepen.io/TimSparrow/pen/xdKAa

```
    <div class="chapters">
<article class="tabs">

    <section id="tab1">
        <h2><a href="#tab1">Summary</a></h2>
    <p><h3>Summary</h3></p>
                   <ul>
                        <li>sample</li>
                    </ul>
    </section>

    <section id="tab2">
        <h2><a href="#tab2">Content</a></h2>
         <p>Long Text Goes Here</p>
    </section>

    <section id="tab3">
        <h2><a href="#tab3">References</a></h2>
        <p>This content appears on tab 3.</p>
    </section>

    <section id="tab4">
        <h2><a href="#tab4">Authors</a></h2>
        <p>This content appears on tab 4.</p>
    </section>

</article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO,

You could try using the `overflow` css property which handles how content should behave if it would overflow the borders of the containing element, and add a height to your content (so it will have the aforementioned content border limit), something as follows:

Wrap your content into a containing element, for example `<div class="sectionContent">`:

```
....
<section id="tab1">
    <h2><a href="#tab1">Summary</a></h2>
    <div class="sectionContent"> 
        <h3>Summary</h3>
        <p>Long text here</p>
        ....
        ....
    </div> // div.sectionContent closed
</section>
....
```

And then add some CSS to the bowl to make it work:

```
.sectionContent{
    overflow-y : scroll;
    height : 15em;
    color:#000;
}
```

Comment: I've also added the `color` attribute to this class' CSS, because you're referencing section > p (as in this case you don't have any direct `p` children within the sections, they are actually `section > .sectionContent > p`.)

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. :)  Thanks Gabor